# Calculate time to go from one point to another point

Tags: kinematics, time

in a 2D football game I want to calculate cycle(time) until ball go from one point
to another point.

in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics) link exist all fomulas that we need for my problem but anyone does not have any parameter that shows the effect of decay on ball speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the acceleration $a(v)$ as a function of speed (as in aerodynamic drag) then

$$ \Delta t = \int_{v_1}^{v_2} \frac{1}{a(v)}\,{\rm d}v $$

For example, a free falling body with air resistance has acceleration (positive is up)

$$ a(v) = \kappa v^2 - g $$

where $\kappa$ is some constant. The time to reach speed $v$ from standstill is

$$ \Delta t = \int_v^0 \frac{1}{\kappa v^2-g}\,{\rm d} v = -\frac{ \ln\left( \frac{\sqrt{g}-\sqrt{\kappa} v}{\sqrt{g}+\sqrt{\kappa} v}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\kappa g}} $$

or the inverse

$$ v(t) = \sqrt{\frac{g}{\kappa}} \, \frac{1-{\rm e}^{-\sqrt{\kappa g}\, 2 t}}{1+{\rm e}^{-\sqrt{\kappa g}\, 2 t}} $$

with terminal velocity

$$ v(t=\infty) = \sqrt{\frac{g}{\kappa}} $$

Comment: thanks,can you please say about what is g and k?

Comment: $g$ is acceleration due to gravity, and $\kappa$ is an aerodynamic constant, typically calculated by $\kappa = \frac{1}{2} \rho A C_d$ with $A$ the swept area, $\rho$ the air density, and $C_d$ the coefficient of drag.

Comment: in soccer simulation 2d that is a field of robotic, we do not have gravity.only agent that effect on speed of ball is ball decay and it has a constant value in each cycle

Comment: You will need a simulation to solve this problem then. That's what computers were invented for, literally the first computers were developed by the army math department to create projectile tables.

Comment: You could use the principles in this paper, http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/AE/aymanma/images/Ballistic%20missile%20trajectory%20prediction%20using%20a%20state%20transition%20matrix.pdf

Comment: thanks for your help,but the link is not very relative to my Question